# I want to extract grades from this array containing subject and grades into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying extract the grades e.g C5,C6 into another array from a string. Sample given below

```
String:

$str = "English Language-C5,Mathematics-C6,Economics-B3,Biology-C5,Geography-B2,Yoruba-B3,Agricultural Science-C6";
```

I created the following function to explode the string above into an array

```
function multiexplode($delimiters,$string) {
    $replace = str_replace(' ', '', $string); // remove spaces between subjects
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $replace);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
print_r(multiexplode(array(" ",",","-"),$str));
// This was the result
Array
(
    [0] => EnglishLanguage
    [1] => C5
    [2] => Mathematics
    [3] => C6
    [4] => Economics
    [5] => B3
    [6] => Biology
    [7] => C5
    [8] => Geography
    [9] => B2
    [10] => Yoruba
    [11] => B3
    [12] => AgriculturalScience
    [13] => C6
)
```

How do I extract the grades(C6,B2...) uniquely into an array. I would appreciate another approach to solve this or what to be done on the code to arrive at the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would parse the string as a CSV then explode on the `-`s.

```
<?php
$str = "English Language-C5,Mathematics-C6,Economics-B3,Biology-C5,Geography-B2,Yoruba-B3,Agricultural Science-C6";
foreach(str_getcsv($str) as $row){
    $values = explode('-', $row);
    $class[] = $values[0];
    $grades[] = $values[1];
}
```

If you really only want grades use the `$grades` array. You also can match to the class if needed. Additionally a `preg_match` could be used on `$values[1]` if you want to verify some pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to extract the grade values, linking them to their subjects in an array:

```
$str = "English Language-C5,Mathematics-C6,Economics-B3,Biology-C5,Geography-B2,Yoruba-B3,Agricultural Science-C6";

preg_match_all('/([^-,]+)-([^,]+)/', $str, $matches);
$grades = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($grades);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [English Language] => C5
    [Mathematics] => C6
    [Economics] => B3
    [Biology] => C5
    [Geography] => B2
    [Yoruba] => B3
    [Agricultural Science] => C6
)
```

If you really only want the values, use `$grades = $matches[2]` instead:

```
$grades = $matches[2];
print_r($grades);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C5
    [1] => C6
    [2] => B3
    [3] => C5
    [4] => B2
    [5] => B3
    [6] => C6
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9GLVZ)

Comment: This works well but I would avoid regex for such simple thing as maintaining a regex has some overheads specifically when non-regex solution is available as mentioned by #user3783243

Comment: @ShaunakSontakke I'd agree with you if the regex was complicated a bit, but it's not complicated at all. Juste with *preg_match_all* you can extract what you need.

Answer (score 2):

OP says: "*How do I extract the grades(C6,B2...) uniquely into an array*"

Assuming the substrings to be extracted always begin with `B`or `C` (which are preceded by a hyphen AND there is always and only one number after the letter, use the following pattern.  The `\K` means restart the fullstring match -- this is done to simplify the output array and avoid the use of a capture group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LqB69))

```
$csv = "English Language-C5,Mathematics-C6,Economics-B3,Biology-C5,Geography-B2,Yoruba-B3,Agricultural Science-C6";

var_export(preg_match_all('~-\K[BC]\d~', $csv, $out) ? array_unique($out[0]) : []);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'C5',
  1 => 'C6',
  2 => 'B3',
  4 => 'B2',
)
```

I don't know if alphabetizing or re-indexing is required, so I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Is there a specific person who is downing all of my regex solutions that are proven to be correct?  Hopefully the system will sniff this person out and ban them because this action on my valuable contributions hurts Stack Overflow and researchers.

Comment: @Lewa if my answer isn't exactly what you are asking for, please update your question to include your exact desired results.  Stack Overflow is a site that aims to help millions of people.  To be a useful resource, questions must be clear, and answers must be correct.  After you edit, I can adjust my answer if it is, in fact, not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match_all

```
$a = "English Language-C5,Mathematics-C6,Economics-B3,Biology-C5,Geography-B2,Yoruba-B3,Agricultural Science-C6";

preg_match_all('#-([BC]\d)#', $a, $res);

if (0 < count($res)) {
    unset($res[0]);
    $res = current($res);
}

print_r($res);
```

The output :

> array ( 0 => 'C5', 1 => 'C6', 2 => 'B3', 3 => 'C5', 4 => 'B2', 5 => 'B3', 6 => 'C6', )